# Use of Tsukerarete in this sentence

Tags: translation

Please can somebody tell me how tsukerarete is being used in this sentence?

最近は誰かに**つけられてる**様な気もしてきた

Comment: "recently I get the feeling that I'm being followed" ? I'm not confident of my  understanding though.

Comment: I thought so. But can you tell me why tsukerareteru means being followed in this sentence? Normally, it means to stick or to apply, right?

Comment: well if you stick close to someone, that's not entirely unlike following.

Answer (score 5):

つける can mean a detective or a maniac/stalker is following someone on the street.  つけられる is its passive form. So,

> 最近は誰かにつけられてる様な気もしてきた

can translate to

> I'm even suspecting someone might be following me on the street

FYI, in a racing (marathon, horse race, F1 race or even election race) つける can mean someone is right behind someone else.

> [総合3番手にタナクがつけている。](http://as-web.jp/news/info.php?c_id=3&no=68950)

(Tänak is the third place finisher (at the moment.))